# Understanding geometric improvement approach for obtaining polynomial-time algorithms

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph-algorithm

I'm reading Network Flows - Theory, Algorithms, and Applications and I'm stuck on the proof of the following theorem (Ch. 3, Page 67):

Theorem. Suppose that ^ is the objective function value of some solution of a minimization problem at the ℎ iteration of an algorithm and ^∗ is the minimum objective function value. Furthermore, suppose that the algorithm guarantees that for every iteration ,

(1) (^ − ^(+1)) ≥ (^ − ^∗)

(i.e., the improvement at iteration  + 1 is at least  times the total possible improvement)for some constant  with 0 <  < 1 (which is independent of the problem data). Then the algorithm terminates in (()/) iterations, where  is the difference between the maximum and minimum objective function values.

Proof. The quantity (^ − ^∗) represents the total possible improvement in the objective function value after the ℎ iteration. Consider a consecutive sequence of 2/ iterations starting from iteration . If each iteration of the algorithm improves the objective function value by at least (^ − ^∗)/2 units, the algorithm would determine an optimal solution within these 2/ iterations. Suppose, instead, that at some iteration  + 1, the algorithm improves the objective function value by less than (^ − ^∗)/2 units. In other words,

(2) ^ − ^(+1) ≤ (^ − ^∗)/2.

The inequality (1) implies that

(3) (^ − ^∗) ≤ ^ − ^(+1)

The inequalities (2) and (3) imply that

(^ − ^∗) ≤ (^ − ^∗)/2,

so the algorithm has reduced the total possible improvement (^ − ^∗) by a factor at least 2. We have thus shown that within 2/ consecutive iterations, the algorithm either obtains an optimal solution or reduces the total possible improvement by a factor of at least 2. Since  is the maximum possible improvement and every objective function value is an integer, the algorithm must terminate within (()/) iterations.

Why does the author focus on 2/a iterations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's written this way for computer scientists to understand more easily that we're halving an integer quantity every 2/α rounds, hence the number of 2/α-round super-rounds will be O(log). No particular reason we can't do the math more directly:

```
T(n) is the gap between the nth solution and an optimal solution.

T(n) ≤ (1 - α) T(n-1) [assumption]


                   n
T(n) ≤ T(0) (1 - α)   [by induction]

              -α n                 x
     < T(0) (e  )     [by 1 + x < e  for x ≠ 0]


                       -α (ln T(0))/α
T((ln T(0))/α) < T(0) e

               = 1,
```

so `(ln T(0))/α` rounds suffice.

Comment: Well, now I don't think I fully understood the original proof. In your proof, where is (1 - a) T(n - 1) coming from?

Comment: @John T(n) here is the gap between the nth solution and the optimal solution.

Comment: I have one last question (about the assumption used in the proof). Why (1-a) instead of a? I guess my question really boils down to: why are we using that assumption and what is the relation between that assumption and the theorem we are proving?

Comment: @John if we gain an alpha fraction of the max improvement, then that's equivalent to saying that the improvement afterward (that we didn't gain) is at most (1-alpha) times the max improvement.

Comment: @John or symbolically: (^ − ^(+1)) ≥ (^ − ^∗) is equivalent to (1-) ^ ≥ ^(+1) − ^∗ by rearranging terms. If we subtract (1-) ^∗ from both sides we get (1-) (^ - ^∗) ≥ ^(+1) − ^∗. Then we let T(n) = ^n - ^∗.